# Erro na consulta com Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

Bem, estou tentando realizar uma consulta no com `Dapper` e obtenho o seguinte erro:

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TaxaDeFertilidade.Models.Pais]', mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo 'TaxaDeFertilidade.Models.Pais'.

Minha entidade `Pais` está assim:

```
[Table("Pais")]
public class Pais
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PaisId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FertilidadePorAno> FertilidadePorAno { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Relatorio(Guid id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var entries = db.Database.Connection.Query<Pais>(@"SELECT * from Pais where PaisId = @id", new { id = id});
    return View(entries);
}
```

E minha **View**:

```
@model TaxaDeFertilidade.Models.Pais

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Relatorio";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Relatorio</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Pais</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

*Debugando*, vi que objeto chega preenchido no `controller`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas no retorno da `View` acontece o problema. Como eu faço para resolve-lo?

Comment: Sua view pede um `Pais` e você está enviando uma coleção de `Pais`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você entregou para a View uma coleção em vez de um ítem único. Tente assim:

```
var entries = db.Database.Connection
                         .Query<Pais>(@"SELECT * from Pais where PaisId = @id", new { id = id})
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note na imagem, que há um `Count`. Isso indica coleção. A view está pedindo um `Pais` não `ICollection<Pais>`